# How to inspect device system information (like RAM size and actual usage) in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ram

Is it possible to check actual RAM usage on a device with nodejs?

Comment: Of your application?  Or from the OS?

Comment: From the Operating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For System, you can check this out

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-os-utils

```
var osu = require('node-os-utils')
var mem = osu.mem
 
mem.info()
  .then(info => {
    console.log(info)
  })
```

It will log below information

```
{ totalMemMb: 16384,
  usedMemMb: 13403.41,
  freeMemMb: 2980.59,
  freeMemPercentage: 18.19 }
```

Similarly, you can do for CPU and device and can run a custom command as well.